# Where do I put the period when I abbreviate someone's name?

Tags: punctuation, abbreviations, names

If I was shortening someone's last name to only the first letter, but not doing it for the first name, would I put the dot after the last name or between the first name and the last name?

For example, is it John.C or John C.?

Answer (score 1):

If you do use a period, it always goes **after** what is being [abbreviated](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/when-you-need-periods-after-abbreviations)

> Dr.  *(doctor, not to be confused with "drive")*
>   St. *(saint, not to be confused with "street")*
>   Ph.D.

However, a period is not always used, especially in BrE, and seems to get  dropped from time to time in AmE, for example in addresses.

In your first example, putting the period *before* the "C" would result in

> John .C

since the period is usually not a word delimiter in written English, otherwise it would be

> John C.Williams

which would be incorrect, however, there are times it might be formatted as

> John C.J. Williams

for contiguous abbreviations.

The famous example which breaks the rules is

> [Will.I.Am](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Will.i.am)

Formatting the abbreviation as

> John.C

looks more programming-ish, "C" is a method for object "John".